# Motorising a bicycle.

Tags: road-bike, motor

Can anyone advise on the best way to motorise a bicycle apart from electric motors? I think I would like to fit a small two stroke engine.

Comment: Buy a motorcycle with a small two stroke engine

Comment: Two stroke motors are noisy and polluting, and not always legal on bicycles. Is there any huge problem with trying an electric motor?

Answer (score 2):

Buy a petrol kit off ebay and follow the instructions.   At that point you fall in a gap between cyclists and bikers, where neither group wants to know about you.

Or buy a new bike designed as an ebike.   Or buy a nifty-50 scooter/step through motorbike.

An electric assist motor is a better idea, the kits cost about the same.  Main difference is you're consuming power to charge, instead of burning petrol+oil.

Electric is much quieter too, whereas motorised bicycles are incredibly loud because of the small mufflers.

Electric kits tend to replace your front wheel, and have a battery bag that hangs on the frame or goes on a rear carrier, or inside a pannier or basket.

Good thing about electric is you're still a cyclist.

Here's my adventures with such a kit http://www.electric-bike-kit-forum.com/post2249.html

Comment: Also a petrol motor might be illegal, since you're no longer a bicycle.

Comment: @bibz excellent point - totally depends on your legal juristiction though.  Here in New Zealand you can have motors up to 300W and pedals, and you're a bicycle.  You can have 49cc petrol and pedals and still be a bicycle.  If you lack functional pedals, then its a motorbike and you need to register it, pay ACC levies, and can get third party vehicle insurance.   You can't get vehicle insurance on a pushbike, - they're treated as "home contents"     
All of this may vary in your country

Comment: @Criggie your understanding of NZ law is not correct, the actual law is [300W and it is officially assumed that combustion engines don't qualify](https://gazette.govt.nz/notice/id/2013-au4618) and more explicitly [the LTSA (who enforce the rules) say only electric is allowed](http://www.nzta.govt.nz/vehicles/vehicle-types/mobility-devices-golf-carts-and-others/) But in Australia, for example, 49cc kits are common and user not prosecuted even though they're illegal.

Comment: Most US laws make your bike a "motorized bike" if the engine is larger than a certain size.  I suspect the cutoff point is such that many electric bikes make under the limit, but few gas-powered ones do.  But a "motorized bike" is still (mostly) subject to bike laws, with the major exception likely being bike paths.

Comment: Again it depends on your location.  The Netherlands permit scooters/ebikes/step-through bikes on bike paths.

Answer (score 1):

The way it was done when I was a kid was to find a small horizontal shaft engine (large chain saw, or some mowers and tillers), attach a drum (roughly 2" diameter) to the shaft, then mount the engine on a board which was somehow suspended off one side of the rear wheel with a mechanism to raise and lower it.

When the engine was started and the drum lowered onto the wheel, the bicycle would move.  If you remembered to mount the engine on the correct side of the bike, the bike would move forward.